# syncing songs from iPhone 4s to Mac

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, iphone, music

I've brought a load of music on my iPhone and have now just purchased a MacBook pro. What is the standard way of transferring songs from iPhone to Mac? Do I need to download all these programs or is there an easier way that I am missing?

Comment: where have you bought the music from?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable "Automatic Downloads" in the iTunes preferences after having your computer authorized.

[image]

Ref : [Apple Support : iTunes Store: How to enable Automatic Downloads](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4539)